# Android facebook friend fetching showing NetworkOnMainThreadException in 4.0 or later android os versions

Tags: android, facebook, networkonmainthread

I am trying to fetch facebook friends in my android app my code is working fine in lower android versions but it's showing **NetworkOnMainThreadException** in 4.0 and later versions.

Here is my code:

```
public static void getFaceBookFriendsIDs() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JSONObject result = new JSONObject(facebook.request("me/friends"));
                    JSONArray friendsArray = result.getJSONArray("data");
                    //friendsList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < friendsArray.length(); i++) {
                        //friendsList.add(friendsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
                        String id=friendsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
                        String name=friendsArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                        contactBean=new ContactBean();
                        contactBean.setFbId(id);
                        contactBean.setUserName(name);
                        com.interactiveapp.Constants.fbContactListArrayList.add(contactBean);
                    }
                } 
                catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } 
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } 
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        /////////////HANDLE RESPONSE//////////
        Message m = new Message();
        m.obj="";
        m.arg1 =1 ;
        saveHandler.dispatchMessage(m);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this lines in >= 4.0 Android os

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

or you can use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16103640/1168654

Comment: is it right way to do this? because this may kill the OS service.

Comment: you can use   asynctask. -->http://stackoverflow.com/a/16103640/1168654

Comment: Use an AsyncTask, or use version 3.0 of the Facebook SDK, and the Request class, which has an async method.